# Build a string with literals and variables

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to build a string for a tool tip, but no matter how I try to build it, I get an error.

This is how I thought I could do it

> tooltipMsg := "Last: " + %lastEmbedState%`n"Curr: " + %embedState%

But it is telling me `Error: The following variable name contains an illegal character: "Last`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names within expressions should not be wrapped in `%`. Also `n represents a new line character and should be inside quotes.

```
tooltipMsg := "Last: " . lastEmbedState . "`n" . "Curr: " . embedState
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Using `.` instead of `+` was the biggest piece of the puzzle I was missing.